# How to add square brackets to values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

Below is my working code:

```
import numpy as np

test = [{"test":np.array([["value1,value1"],["value2,value2"]])},{"names": 
                                                        ["test1","test2"]}]
q = ["value3,value3"]
v = ["test3"]

for p in test:
    for item,value in p.items(): 
        if str(item).startswith("test"):
            p["test"] = np.append(p["test"],np.array([q]))
        

        if str(item).startswith("names"):
            for r in v:
                p["names"].append(r)
```

I need output as following:

```
[{'test': array([['value1,value1'], ['value2,value2'], ['value3', 'value3']], 
                                                   dtype='<U13')},
 {'names': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}]
```

but currently im getting like below:

```
[{'test': array(['value1,value1', 'value2,value2', 'value3', 'value3'], dtype='<U13')},
   {'names': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}]
```

Where am I doing silly mistake ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to append to a specific axis:

```
for p in test:
    for item,value in p.items(): 
        if str(item).startswith("test"):
            p["test"] = np.append(p['test'], [q], axis=0) # changed here
        

        if str(item).startswith("names"):
            for r in v:
                p["names"].append(r)
```

output:

```
[{'test': array([['value1,value1'],
                 ['value2,value2'],
                 ['value3,value3']], dtype='<U13')},
 {'names': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}]
```

Comment: Hi @mozway , Please see my expected output ! i need square brackets around values inside "test" keys. 

example:  
[{'test': array([['value1,value1'], ['value2,value2'], ['value3', 'value3']],  dtype='<U13')}]

Comment: actually, it should be `p['test']`